# brew not linking gcc after install?

Tags: macos, homebrew, open-source, gcc

Why does brew not link gcc properly? 
What am I missing?

```
$>brew install gcc49 --without-multilib
==> Installing gcc49 from homebrew/homebrew-versions
==> Downloading http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/gcc/gcc-4.9.3/gcc-4.9.3.tar.bz2
==> Downloading from http://gnu.mirror.iweb.com/gcc/gcc-4.9.3/gcc-4.9.3.tar.bz2
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc49/4.9.3 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc49/4.9.3/lib/gc
==> make bootstrap
==> make install
  /usr/local/Cellar/gcc49/4.9.3: 1079 files, 146M, built in 27.3 minutes
$>which gcc49   // <--------- NOTHING SHOWS UP HERE
$>which gcc  // <--------- NOTHING SHOWS UP HERE
$>
```

I event tried `brew unlink gcc49 && brew link gcc49`
What am I missing?

Comment: When you do the brew link & unlink commands, what does it say?

Comment: Already linked. ok looks like the executables are named gcc-4.9 and not gcc.

Comment: if you fixed your problem, then create an answer saying what you did, and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1):

The executables are named gcc-4.9 and not gcc
I fixed it by going to:

```
$>cd /usr/local/Cellar/gcc49/4.9.3/bin
$>ln -s gcc-4.9 gcc
$>ln -s g++-4.9 g++
$> cd ~
$>brew link gcc
```

Comment: don't you mean `ln -s` instead of `ln -x`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe all the homebrew gcc variants don't get linked as gcc. You could look in /usr/local/bin and sort by time or check in the `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc49/4.9.3/bin` folder where the binaries all actually get built as opposed to sym linked to /usr/local/bin

```
ls -lrt /usr/local/bin | tail -20
```